# Web App using Google Apps Script not working with distributed URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

**What the program does:** I have written a simple Google Apps Script that retrieves unread emails from a label in the Gmail account currently logged in, and returns the number of those emails, and displays it on the website.

**Problem:** This program works when I created a web app from the computer I developed it on, and run it from the website. However, if I copy the URL and distribute it to another computer that is logged in as another Google account, it doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
/*Sample.gs*/ 
function doGet(e){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Run.html');
}

function GetUnreadCount(sourceLabel){
    return GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(sourceLabel).getUnreadCount();
}

function Main()
{   
    /*For testing, return unread email count from "CustomerA" label of Gmail*/
    return GetUnreadCount("CustomerA");
}
```

.

```
/*Run.html*/
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        function CallGetUnreadCount() {

          document.getElementById('Messages').innerHTML = 'Counting...';

          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
            .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
            .Main();          
        }

        function onSuccess(UnreadCount) 
        {
          document.getElementById('Messages').innerHTML = "There are " + UnreadCount + " unread emails.";
        }

        function onFailure(error) 
        {
          document.getElementById('Messages').innerHTML = "Err: " + error.message;
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <h1 id="Messages">Count # of unread emails</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick='CallGetUnreadCount();' id="CountButton">Count Unread Emails</button> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This program works fine if I run it on the computer I wrote this script on. However, if I deploy it as a web app, and distribute the URL (ending with `/exec`), and run it on another computer that has logged in as a different Gmail account, it always returns 0 even when there are unread emails in `CustomerA` label.
What confuses me is, this same program works on another computer if I create a new project on that computer and copy-paste the above code into a `.gs` file and an `html` file, and deploy as a web app.

Why does the same program work if each computer deploys the web app on their own, but not work if I distribute the URL?

Comment: Can you provide the information about the settings of "Deploy as web app" and "Execute the app as" for deploying your Web Apps? And I cannot understand about `each computer` of `if each computer deploys the web app on their own`. `each computer` means each Google account?

Comment: @Tanaike-san, 以前もお世話になりました。再びありがとうございます。まず、コンピュータAでこのプログラムを書き、スクリプト画面のPublishを選択しDeploy As Web Appを選択しました。そこで、Web AppのURLは取得でき、そのWebサイトからこのプログラムを実行すると、ちゃんと未読メールの件数を取得できます。このコンピュータは、仮にAさんのGoogleアカウントでログインしており、AさんのGmailには、CustomerAというラベルがあります。そこの未読件数を数えます。　
そして、このDeployされたWebAppのURLを別のコンピュータBにメールか何かで送ります。このコンピュータBは、Bさんがログインしていますが、BさんのGmailにもCustomerAというラベルがあります。同じWeb AppのURLを使って、Bさんも自身のCustomerAラベルから未読件数を数えたいのです。しかし、なぜかこれができず、いつも「０」が返ってきます。しかし、コンピュータAから、このGSファイルとHTMLファイルをメール等でコンピュータBへ送り、新プロジェクトを作成し、これらのコードを同じようにコピーし、そこからDeploy As Web Appをすると、コンピュータBでもWebAppがちゃんと動きます。同じコードなのに不思議です。

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, if you are using the script editor with Japanese language, when you select "ウェブアプリケーションとして導入" and open a dialog, what are the values of `Execute the app as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? I thought that your issue might be resolved by the settings of Web Apps.

Comment: Who has access to the app はAnyoneにしていましたが、 Execute the app as のところは、コンピュータAのアカウントになっていました＾＾；そこを設定しなおすと直りました。こんな単純なことに何時間も悩んでいました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. 無事解決したとのことで安心しました。 For example, about the settings of Web Apps, is this information useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script  When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike 自分で回答を投稿するということですか？どのように 自分の質問を post it as an answer するのでしょうか？このコメントセクションは本回答ではないので、@Tanaikeさんのコメントを解決回答として選択もできませんよね。

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, J.Doe. I have created a community wiki for this question. Please take a look at it and feel free to modify it as appropriate (I'm afraid I don't quite understand Japanese too well). Also, please bear in mind that the language used in StackOverflow [has to be english](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/). Thank you both!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Deploying as web app (`Publish > Deploy as web app`), there are a few options to configure:

[image: deploy as web app]

- **Execute the app as**: Can be either *Me*, or *User accessing the web app*. For your case, you must use the later to make it work as you expect.
- **Who has access to this app**: Can be either *Only myselft*, *Anyone within your domain* or *Anyone*. You have to make sure it's either the 2nd or 3rd option, depending on your needs, so that the user can properly execute it.